# Some visual bug with CALayer

Tags: ios, uiimageview, calayer, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I have a UITableView with the following cells layout:

• UIView

•• UIImageView

••• Semi-transparent overlay UIView as subview of UIImageView

There are also icon view imitating the "play" button and UILabel, but they seem to be not related to this bug.

And I have the following code:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        createPath()
    }

    private func createPath() {
        let padding = CGFloat(16)
        let bottomLineLength = CGFloat(64)
        let arcPadding = CGFloat(8)

        let width = self.contentView.frame.width
        let height = self.contentView.frame.height

        if pathLayer != nil {
            pathLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()
        }

        pathLayer = CAShapeLayer()

        let path = UIBezierPath()

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: padding + arcPadding, y: padding))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width - padding - arcPadding, y: padding))

        // Top-Right arc
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: width - padding - arcPadding, y: padding + arcPadding),
                    radius: arcPadding,
                    startAngle: CGFloat(3 * M_PI / 2),
                    endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI * 2),
                    clockwise: true)

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: width - padding, y: padding + arcPadding))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width - padding, y: height - padding - arcPadding))

        // Bottom-Right arc
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: width - padding - arcPadding, y: height - padding - arcPadding),
                    radius: arcPadding,
                    startAngle: CGFloat(M_PI * 2),
                    endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI / 2),
                    clockwise: true)
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: width - padding - arcPadding, y: height - padding))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width - padding - bottomLineLength, y: height - padding))

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: padding + bottomLineLength, y: height - padding))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: padding + arcPadding, y: height - padding))

        // Bottom-Left arc
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: padding + arcPadding, y: height - padding - arcPadding),
                    radius: arcPadding,
                    startAngle: CGFloat(M_PI / 2),
                    endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI),
                    clockwise: true)

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: padding, y: height - padding - arcPadding))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: padding, y: padding + arcPadding))

        // Top-Left arc
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: padding + arcPadding, y: padding + arcPadding),
                    radius: arcPadding,
                    startAngle: CGFloat(M_PI),
                    endAngle: CGFloat(3 * M_PI / 2),
                    clockwise: true)

        pathLayer?.rasterizationScale = 2 * UIScreen.main.scale
        pathLayer?.shouldRasterize = true
        pathLayer?.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 0xFF/255, green: 0xFF/255, blue: 0xFF/255, alpha: 0.5).cgColor
        pathLayer?.lineWidth = 2.0
        pathLayer?.path = path.cgPath

        contentView.layer.addSublayer(pathLayer!)
    }
```

I'm calling it in layoutSubviews for re-creating the path on device rotation.

And if you look at the screenshot, there are some black and rotated a bit black "holes" near the path. All of them look the same, and they are surely not present on the image in UIImageView.

[image: Screenshot]

I think it's related to my CALayer. How to fix it?

Comment: There is a black wedge along the inside left edge of each rounded rectangle. It's visible if you zoom way in. There are also wedges along the top, right, and lower left edges.

Comment: @robmayoff I'm glad you see what he means!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is these black wedges:

[image: black wedges]

The underlying cause is that the default `fillColor` of a `CAShapeLayer` is opaque black. Set it to nil to avoid filling:

```
pathLayer?.fillColor = nil
```

That done, let me show you a shorter way to construct your path:

```
let cgPath = CGMutablePath()
let start = CGPoint(x: padding + bottomLineLength, y: height - padding)
let blCorner = CGPoint(x: padding, y: height - padding)
let tlCorner = CGPoint(x: padding, y: padding)
let trCorner = CGPoint(x: width - padding, y: padding)
let brCorner = CGPoint(x: width - padding, y: height - padding)
let end = CGPoint(x: width - padding - bottomLineLength, y: height - padding)

cgPath.move(to: start)
cgPath.addArc(tangent1End: blCorner, tangent2End: tlCorner, radius: arcPadding)
cgPath.addArc(tangent1End: tlCorner, tangent2End: trCorner, radius: arcPadding)
cgPath.addArc(tangent1End: trCorner, tangent2End: brCorner, radius: arcPadding)
cgPath.addArc(tangent1End: brCorner, tangent2End: end, radius: arcPadding)
cgPath.addLine(to: end)

shapeLayer.path = cgPath
```

Result:

[image: no wedges]